# Use angular expression outside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know this question has been asked for many times, but most of the answer give the idea to use controller. For my question, I don't want to use any controller, only at view.

I have this on my view:

```
<p data-ng-repeat="ticketA in cart.sw_tickets" ng-if="ticketA.ProductId == tickets.ProductId && ticketA.PricingTypeId == 1" data-ng-init="adulttotTicket = ticketA.total_ticket">{{adulttotTicket}}</p>
```

I want `adulttotTicket` can be use after ng-repeat, supposedly after element `<p></p>`. I have tried this:

```
<p data-ng-repeat="ticketA in cart.sw_tickets" ng-if="ticketA.ProductId == tickets.ProductId && ticketA.PricingTypeId == 1" data-ng-init="adulttotTicket = ticketA.total_ticket"></p>{{adulttotTicket}}
```

But seems like I can't get this value `adulttotTicket`.

**note***  I don't want use any controller

Hope anyone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Why dont use a <div> who contains the <p> and the text?

Comment: so ng-repeat inside`<div>` ?

Comment: I have tried put ng-repeat inside  `<div>` and call `adulttotTicket` in `<p>`. I think it is same.
`<div ng-repeat="..." > <p>adulttotTicket<p> </div>`

Comment: In an MV* framework, the model should drive the view. Having the HTML drive the model is backwards from the Zen of AngularJS. In addition `ng-repeat` creates a child scope form each item and `ng-if` creates a child scope for each item. It is a hideously inefficient way to do something which can be done easily in a controller.

Answer (score 1):

Assign it to `$rootScope`.

Working Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/GtDNj7BRgb5M1MAb3u5V?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the example, its working!  Do you any idea where can I learn that syntax instead from the document? I'm really new with `angular`

Comment: I can use`$rootScope.adulttotTicket` easily. but have a little problem, I try to assign new variable to `$rootScope.adulttotTicket`: `<p data-ng-init="newVar = $rootScope.adulttotTicket`, then I output the `newVar`. it return `0`

Answer (score 0):

The variable ticketA is only available inside the scope of ng-repeat. So, in your case i would use some nested divs to handle the problem.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="ticketA in cart.sw_tickets">
   <div ng-if="ticketA.ProductId == tickets.ProductId && ticketA.PricingTypeId == 1" data-ng-init="adulttotTicket = ticketA.total_ticket">
      <p>{{ticketA}}</p> {{adulttotTicket}}
   <div>
</div>
```